# how to add vertical lines to a table view in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i m making an application which shows data on table view with many fields i also want to add vertical lines to table view to make it like a chart ?is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this: [Tutorial: Drawing a Grid in a iPhone UITableView](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153)?

Comment: Link appears broken now