# Draw a vertical line down table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to draw a vertical line between the SectionIndex column and the cell content view. How can I do this?

[image: Split table view with table data and sorted keys]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this post:

[how to add vertical lines to a table view in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836823/how-to-add-vertical-lines-to-a-table-view-in-iphone-sdk)

Refer to **Kris Markel's** there in the above post. It suggests this link:

http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153

**Note:** I have copied code from the whole link and pasted it here, just to make sure answer remains useful even in case if the link goes down in future:

> UITableView is probably the most used view on the iPhone. It’s
>   flexible and the UI is ideally suited to use on the iPhone. There are
>   lots of examples on how to add multiple items to a UITableViewCell.
>   However, I needed to present some data in a more traditional
>   spreadsheet style grid. The results worked well and enabled me to pack
>   a lot of information on the screen that was very hard to follow
>   without the vertical grid. I’ll show a very simplified version here
>   you can use to add vertical lines to your UITableView.
>
> **First we need to create a subclass of UITableViewCell. This is so we
>   can override drawrect and draw our lines** and to add an array to hold a
>   list of positions where we’ll draw the lines.

```
@interface MyTableCell : UITableViewCell {
    NSMutableArray *columns;
}
- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position;
@end
```

> In this simplified example we’ll leave the positioning of the actual
>   text in the cells in the UITableViewController and place it manually
>   (full source code is attached at the end). We’re just providing a
>   mechanism for drawing vertical lines to make a grid. Column locations
>   are added by calling addColumn:

```
- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position {
    [columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
}
```

> Now lets override drawRect. In it we grab the current graphics context
>   and set the line color and width. Then we iterate over our columns
>   array drawing a line from the top of the cell row to the bottom at
>   each position stored in the array.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Use the same color and width as the default cell separator for now
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.25);

    for (int i = 0; i &lt; [columns count]; i++) {
        CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
To add columns to the view just call

[cell addColumn:50];
when you’re building each cell.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 30.0,
                                                           tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
        [cell addColumn:50];
        label.tag = LABEL_TAG;
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 0, 30.0,
                                                            tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
        [cell addColumn:120];
        label.tag = VALUE_TAG;
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        // add some silly value
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Princekumar: Refer to my answer and see if it helps you.

Comment: @Princekumar: My answer works without scrolling table view. It comes from the very first time table is being displayed. Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: @Princekumar: You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and then overwrite the `drawRect` method in there. Also I have edited my answer and made the line **bold** which explains you what it is. If you require more help or you have any doubts then please let me know.

Comment: I applied this answer and it is working perfectly again thanks for it.

Comment: Mr Parth Bhatt there is no issue that it is working perfectly but it created two column in the cell not a line between the cell contentView and SectionIndex View as I have displayed above.Please take a look in my answer this will confirm u what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I have use following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath , and this is working perfectly.

```
static NSString *reuse = @"reuse";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuse];


if(cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuse];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}



 [cell.contentView  setBounds:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x, cell.bounds.origin.y, 222,60)];

NSString *year = [self.keys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *movieSection = [[self.dataAllArtists objectForKey:year] valueForKey:@"row"];
NSDictionary *performanceDic = [movieSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

 cell.textLabel.text = [NetworkData parseString:[performanceDic valueForKey:@"performance_name"]];


    int x;
    switch ([genreId intValue]) 
    {
     case 1:
      x=cell.contentView.bounds.size.width+19;
      break;
     case 3:
      x=cell.contentView.bounds.size.width+26;
      break;
      case 6:
      x=cell.contentView.bounds.size.width+16;
      break;
      case 7:
      x=cell.contentView.bounds.size.width+28;
      break;
     default:
      break;
    }

        for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews])
        {
         if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
         {
          [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
         }
        }

  [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

  UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,0,1, cell.contentView.bounds.size.height+2)] autorelease];


  lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];


return cell;
```